# getting response from post request

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

I'm trying to do simple login modal using POST jQuery AJAX,
but I'm not getting any response from the server

client:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#loginReq").click(function(){
                $.post("/login",
                {
                    uname: document.getElementById("username").value,
                    psw: document.getElementById("password").value
                },
                function(data, status, jqXHR) {
                    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                });
            });
        });
```

server:

```
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
var username = req.body.uname;
var password = req.body.psw;
var i;
for (i=0; i < users.length; i++)
    if (username == users[i].username && password == users[i].password)
    {
        console.log('found');
        //res.send('OK');
        //res.sendStatus(200);
        res.status(200).send('OK');
        break;
    }
if (i == users.length)
{
    console.log('not found');
    res.sendStatus(300);
}
console.log('end of listener');
});
```

I've tried res.sent, res.end, res.statusCode, res.status.send,
but whatever I tried the alert on the client side won't pop.

(my goal is to get an empty response - only status code, no body,
but nothing works)

Comment: Console errors server and client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example that should help you I think.

First `npm install body-parser`

On your server use the body-parser middleware:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/login', (req, res)=> {
    res.send(JSON.stringify(req.body));
});
```

In your jQuery file prevent the form from submitting - note here `loginReq` is an id on the form itself:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#loginReq').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({ 
           url: '/login',
           type: 'POST',
           cache: false, 
           data: {"username": document.getElementById("username").value}, 
           success: function(data){
              alert(data);
           }
           , error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, err){
               alert('error ' + err);
           }
        });    
    });
});
```

This will pop up an alert with your data.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined a server on the backend, but you haven't started it up. Check out the example code on the express website [here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) to see how to start up your server.

TL;DR - try adding the following to the bottom of the server file:

```
app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```